# Get objects queue from network and walk prev/next

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I have application, which loads data from network on press Next button. I want add prev button and possibility to show previous data without request in network. How can I realize this? I looking at Volley library, but I don't know have Volley this feature or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volley caches results by default once the request is completed. So yes, you could use volley to do what you want. Here is a [link](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/clinton-teegarden/android-volley-library-tutorial) to a tutorial.

Another option would be to store the result from the request in a SQLite database and retrieve it if the user goes back to the previous screen. If you are using Volley I will just use their cache to retrieve the data.

Comment: But, my url is same for loading items. How volley will be cache result? I have no parameters in url